# Modified Sutherland Hodgeman Algorithm

Tags: algorithms, graphics, polygons

I'm familiar with applying the sutherland hodgeman algorithm for convex polygons(and even concave polygons with a slight modification) against convex clipping windows.

However, if I am to modify the sutherland hodgeman algorithm in such a way that I can clip a concave polygon against a concave window, is that possible?

My question is precisely this:[image]

It's a question that has come in my exam and the only thing I thought of was using the Weiler Atherton algorithm, but that's no amendment to the Sutherland Hodgman approach and is a different algorithm altogether.